# How can I get all files in a directory, but not in subdirectories, in Perl?

Tags: perl, file, find

How can I find all the files that match a certain criteria (`-M`, modification age in days) in a list of directories, but not in their subdirectories?

I wanted to use File::Find, but looks like it always goes to the subdirectories too.

Comment: What are "certain criteria"? Size, permissions, names, dates, anything?

Comment: @Manni: -M, modification age in days

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
@files = grep { -f && (-M) < 5 } <$_/*> for @folders;
```

Comment: when doing multiple -X's on the same file, you can use _ as the "filename" on all but the first to reuse the same stat return

Answer (score 2):

Use [readdir](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html) or [File::Slurp::read_dir](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/File::Slurp) in conjunction with [grep](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html).

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Slurp;
use File::Spec::Functions qw( canonpath catfile );

my @dirs = (@ENV{qw(HOME TEMP)});

for my $dir ( @dirs ) {
    print "'$dir'\n";
    my @files = grep { 2 > -M and -f }
                map { canonpath(catfile $dir, $_) } read_dir $dir;
    print "$_\n" for @files;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set File::Find::prune within the 'wanted' function to skip directory trees.  Add something like $File::Find::prune = 1 if( -d && $File::Find::name ne ".");

Comment: If you don't want to do a depth first search, don't use a depth first search tool. :)